# User controls vs Custom Controls Silverliht

Tags: silverlight

For developing a dashboard which will have many different widgets available, graphs, grids, etc, is a user control the best thing to use or a custom control?

I am a bit confused about the best situations to use each of them in

This relates to Silverlight 5

Paul

Answer (score 2):

The key difference between user controls and custom controls is that custom controls can be re-templated, i.e. you can completely change their visuals by supplying a different template. If you do not need to do this in your application, I would recommend using user-controls as a simple alternative.

I have written a blog post about how to create them here:

[A Simple Pattern for Creating Re-useable UserControls in WPF / Silverlight](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/)